# Does the size of the alphabet of a register machine affect its expressive power?

Tags: logic, computability

Consider a register machine which computes a function from $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$. By computing a function it's meant that a register machine with alphabet $\{a\}$, starting with $x$ number of $a$ letters as its input will print $y$ number of $a$ letter's and halt. $x$ and $y$ are the input/output of the function.

Question, does extending the alphabet to for example $\{a,b\}$ increase the computational power of the register machine (i.e. is there a function that can be computed only with the extended alphabet)?

Comment: What definition of register machine are you using? With the [usual defnitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine), the registers hold integers and there is no notion of alphabet.

Comment: @RobArthan Here is a definition from Mathematical logic by Ebbinghaus. https://snag.gy/SfhL8l.jpg

Comment: OK - then with that definition and a single letter in the alphabet, one approach to your problem is to see if you can simulate a register machine whose registers hold natural numbers, e.g., by representing the natural number $n$ as a string of $n$ $a$s?